# Real time data consumption from mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-batch, real-time

I have a use case in which my data is present in **Mysql**.

For each new row insert in Mysql, I have to perform analytics for the new data.

**How I am currently solving this problem is**:

My application is a **Spring-boot** application, in which I have used **Scheduler** which checks for new row entered in the database **after every 2 seconds**.

The **problem with the current approach is**:

Even if there is no new data available in Mysql table, Scheduler fires MySQL query to check if new data available or not.

One way to solve this type of problem in any SQL database in **Triggers** .

But till now I am **not successful in creating Mysql triggers** which can call **Java**-based Spring **application** or a simple java application.

My question is :

Is their any better way to solve my above use-case? Even I am open to change to another storage (database) system if they are built for this type of use-case.

Comment: do you a control at the application from where you insert data?

Comment: IMHO It's not the databases job to worry about how x-number of consumers are using it's data. Your current implementation is fine but if you are looking for a "trigger", why not look for it in your application at the point you are inserting the new data to begin with? If you need something real time and responsive you could look into messaging?

Comment: Are your spring repositories the only source of data changes or you actually have other applications that can mess with your data?

Comment: Insertion is being done by a remote server, of which I do not have any control.

Comment: in that case you don't have any option other than reading mysqlbinlog, this 'll be the same process as you are already doing like reading after a specific interval of time, but the only advantage you have this time is you are not hurting mysql by executing your large number of un necessary queries.

Comment: @PrakashPandey I think you already have the easiest approach.  Probably you could implement C/C++ User-Defined Function to notify you https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-udf.html  Here is demo https://github.com/Cyclonecode/mysql-notification But who know is it worth it in your case

Answer (score 2):

This fundamentally sounds like an architecture issue.  You're essentially using a database as an API which, as you can see, causes all kinds of issues.  Ideally, this db would be wrapped in a service that can manage the notification of systems that need to be notified.  Let's look at a few different options going forward.

**Continue to poll**
You didn't outline what the actual issue is with your current polling approach.  Is running the job when it's not needed causing an issue of some kind?  I'd be a proponent for just leaving it unless you're interested in making a larger change.

**Database Trigger**
While I'm unaware of a way to launch a java process via a db trigger, you can do an HTTP POST from one.  With that in mind, you can have your batch job staged in a web app that uses a POST to launch the job when the trigger fires.

**Wrap existing datastore in a service**
This is, IMHO, the best option.  This allows there to be a system of record that provides an API that can be versioned, etc.  This would allow any logic around who to notify would also be encapsulated into this service.

**Replace data store with something that allows for better notifications**
Without any real information on what the data being store is, it's hard to say how practical this is.  But using something as Apache Kafka or Apache Geode would both be options that provide the ability to be notified when new data is persisted (Kafka by listening to the topic, Geode via a continuous query).

For the record, I'd advocate for the wrapping of the existing database in a service.  That service would be the only way into the db and take on responsibility for any notifications required.